# QT SQLite "No query Unable to fetch row"

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I have this class DatabaseManager that is handles SQlite Database in Qt
the problem is some times the Query return "No query Unable to fetch row" and returns nothing even though the database has records in it and some times the query works perfectly fine 
can any one help figure out this problem ?

here is the class:

```
class DatabaseManager
{
private:
    QSqlDatabase PatternLibrary;
    QSqlQuery query;


public:
    Pattern pattern;
    std::vector<Pattern> allPatterns;
    std::vector<QString> patternNames;
    std::vector<RECTANGLE> rectangles_;
    DatabaseManager()
    {
        PatternLibrary = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase( "QSQLITE" );
        PatternLibrary.setDatabaseName("mydb");
        bool opened = PatternLibrary.open();
        query = QSqlQuery(PatternLibrary);
        if(opened)
        {
            qDebug( "Connected!");
            query.prepare( "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Pattern (patternName         VARCHAR(30),RectangleID INTEGER ,X1 INTEGER, Y1 INTEGER, X2 INTEGER, Y2 INTEGER,X3     INTEGER,Y3 INTEGER, X4 INTEGER, Y4 INTEGER,PRIMARY KEY (patternName,RectangleID))" );
            bool create = query.exec();
            if(!create)
            {
                qDebug() <<PatternLibrary.lastError().text();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << PatternLibrary.lastError().text();
            qFatal( "Failed to connect." );
        }
        query.clear();
    }

//******************************************************************************//
 bool select_all_records()
    {
        query = QSqlQuery(PatternLibrary);
        query.clear();
        if(PatternLibrary.open())
        {
            query.prepare( "SELECT* FROM Pattern");
            if(!query.exec())
            {
                qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
                query.clear();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                int PatternCount=0;
                QString temp1="",temp2="";
                patternNames.clear();
                while( query.next() )
                {
                    temp1 = query.value(0).toString();
                    if(temp1 !=temp2)
                    {
                        PatternCount++;
                        temp2 = temp1;
                        patternNames.push_back(temp1);
                    }
                    RECTANGLE Rect;
                    Rect.patternName = query.value(0).toString();
                    Rect.rectangleId = query.value(1).toInt();
                    Rect.X1 = query.value(2).toInt();
                    Rect.Y1 = query.value(3).toInt();
                    Rect.X2 = query.value(4).toInt();
                    Rect.Y2 = query.value(5).toInt();
                    Rect.X3 = query.value(6).toInt();
                    Rect.Y3 = query.value(7).toInt();
                    Rect.X4 = query.value(8).toInt();
                    Rect.Y4 = query.value(9).toInt();
                    rectangles_.push_back(Rect);
                }
                for(unsigned int i =0;i<patternNames.size();i++)
                {
                    Pattern newPattern;
                    newPattern.PatternName = patternNames.at(i);
                    for(unsigned int j =0;j<rectangles_.size();j++)
                    {
                        if(rectangles_[j].patternName == newPattern.PatternName)
                        {
                            newPattern.pattern_.push_back(rectangles_[j]);
                            rectangles_.erase(rectangles_.begin()+j);
                            j--;
                        }

                    }
                    allPatterns.push_back(newPattern);
                }
                query.clear();
                return true;
            }
        }
        query.clear();
        qFatal( "Can't Open database" );
        return false;
    }
//************************************************************//
```

here is my main:

```
int main()
{
    DatabaseManager *mydbmanager = new DatabaseManager();
    bool b = mydbmanager-> select_all_records();  //returns false and "No query Unable to fetch row"
}
```

Comment: Why is `QSqlQuery` an instance variable rather than a stack variable?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by that ?? should i create it for every statement execution ??

Comment: Well I'm no expert, but I would expect so.

Comment: I am clearing the query every time i use it but even when i used a new instance for every Query it still fails sometimes..

Comment: Just making an assumption here, when you deployed it: it worked the first time, didn't on the next few times then worked once again (repeating)?

Comment: it never works on the first time, then in every 10 times i use a query it misses one time (rough estimation)